# Compare project between changesets in TFS VC web portal

Tags: tfs, diff, pull-request

Like a pull request in Git, I'm wanting to produce a similar result through the TFS web portal by comparing changesets, or dates, or whatever mechanism exists. I've found https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/compare-folders-files but it is demonstrated through Visual Studio, rather than through TFS site's project dashboard.

I'm not looking to compare individual files, 1 by 1, but to (again) produce something similar to the diff you'd see in a git pull request, which in my tooling (BitBucket) has a treeview on the left on which you can see changed files, and after choosing a file, seeing on the right a diff between the two states.

If this can't be done in the TFS web portal, and MUST be done in VS, I think the instructions on the above link are probably adequate, as it describes comparing folders between two changesets.

How is this accomplished in TFS world thru web portal?  Hope that's not too vague, I don't know the TFS domain language with which to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to install [git-tfs](https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs) and [git for windows](https://git-for-windows.github.io/). Then you can browse through all changesets fast and easily with the [gitk tool](https://lostechies.com/joshuaflanagan/2010/09/03/use-gitk-to-understand-git/).

Comment: even if the projects are tfsvc and not tfsgit?  are you saying i'd be able to review pull requests through the web portal?  i already know how to do this with visual studio.  what i'm trying to accomplish is diffs though the web portal, similar to BitBucket and others.

Comment: git-tfs is a gateway add-on to git that imports from (and possibly exports to) tfs server content into a local git repository on your machine. As such it is completely disconnected from the tfs server and web portal, so if it absolutely must go through some web frontend this suggestion will not provide it (unless you install [gitweb](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitweb) in addition). But it will allow you to browse through changes locally using the gitk program which while not "modern" ui design, it is many orders of magnitude faster and much more convinient than any official tfs method.

Answer (score 0):

For TFVC, you can view changes made in changesets on the "History" view of the "Code" hub.

[image]

When you choose a changeset, you'll see all of the changes made as part of that changeset. If you want to compare two changesets (as opposed to comparing current to previous), there's nothing in the web UI.